# What is meant by MAC address "Spoofing"

Tags: networking, router, internet, modem, mac-address

Why is MAC address Spoofing called spoofing, rather than MAC address changing?  If the network sees your MAC address as whatever you spoofed it to, doesn't that practically meant you have completely changed your MAC address?

Answer (score 3):

What you say is essentially true, you change your MAC address. However, the meaning of 'spoofing' in a computer security context indicates malicious intent:

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoofing_attack:

> In the context of network security, a spoofing attack is a situation
>   in which one person or program successfully masquerades as another by
>   falsifying data and thereby gaining an illegitimate advantage.

So the difference between 'configuring a different MAC address' and 'spoofing a MAC address' is mostly defined by the intent of the user.

Comment: To let my XBox use the hotel wifi, I had to spoof the MAC address of the laptop that I used to connect and authorize the service. Basically you trick the network into thinking you're someone different.

Comment: I would call that 'changing the MAC address'. Spoofing indicates you are trying to capture traffic destined for another host, but I have to admit it's a fine line. Kudo's for using your XBox at a hotel though, that's dedication ;)

Comment: Well I called it spoofing because I used it to disguise the Xbox as the previously authorized laptop so I could get pass their sign in portal. It was a while ago, I think I was trying to keep an online play record or something LOL.

Answer (score 1):

A MAC address is a BIA (burned-in address) on the hardware and any change to it (from software) is not permanent.

The original one was burned on your hardware and it's not possible to change it at least you change the piece.

Hence the "spoofing".

Answer (score 0):

Much like physics, networking is relative on your perspective.

From the distant end, it's changed completely.
From the application layer, it's altered by spoofing.
From the Hardware layer, it'll never change.